# Facebook app invite is not working in iOS8 using Facebook SDK 4.X?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have implement facebook app invite functionality by using following code. But my app is getting crash due to undefined selector error.
I have try to debug or search this type of error on google But unable to find any clue.

```
 FBSDKAppInviteContent *content =[[FBSDKAppInviteContent alloc] init];
    content.appLinkURL = contentURL;
    //optionally set previewImageURL
    //content.appInvitePreviewImageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:imgUrl];

        [FBSDKAppInviteDialog showWithContent:content
                                     delegate:nil];
```

//--Error is coming as following

> -[FBSDKApplicationDelegate openBridgeAPIRequest:completionBlock:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16da1250
>       *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[FBSDKApplicationDelegate
>   openBridgeAPIRequest:completionBlock:]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0x16da1250'
>       *** First throw call stack:
>       (0x28232fef 0x36b76c8b 0x28238409 0x28236327 0x28165e78 0x15d491 0x15d1c1 0x114aa9 0x2b8e0ddb 0x2b8e0d81 0x2b8cb973 0x2b8e07ed
>   0x2b8e04c7 0x2b8d9da1 0x2b8aff95 0x2bb268ab 0x2b8ae9a9 0x281f8faf
>   0x281f83bf 0x281f6a25 0x28143201 0x28143013 0x2fc14201 0x2b90fa09
>   0xd0ca1 0x37128aaf)
>       libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Thanks in advance, It's really appreciated if any one give any clue on this.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
[FBSDKAppInviteDialog showFromViewController:viewController withContent:content delegate:weakSelf];
```

showWithContent:delegate is already deprecated.